# Setting a Simulink block's number of output ports depending on its inport datatypes in a level 2 C-mex S-Function

Tags: c, matlab, mex, simulink

I'm trying to create a level 2 S-Function written in C that has *different numbers of output ports* depending on the *signals' datatypes* that are connected to the inports.

The practical background is that I have some other S-Functions that define custom datatypes by calling `ssRegisterDataType`. These datatypes describe pointers to certain data.

I now want to have another S-Function that can consume these custom datatypes (pointers) and, depending on what pointer type is fed into them, output certain data.

I tried setting the number of output ports through `ssSetNumOutputPorts` by

```
static void mdlSetInputPortDataType(SimStruct *S, int portIndex,DTypeId dType)
{
    if( portIndex == 0 )
    {
        if(      dType == ssGetDataTypeId(S, "ptrtype1" ) )
        {
            if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, nOutportsPtr1)) return;
        }
        else if( dType == ssGetDataTypeId(S, "ptrtype2" ) )
        {
            if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, nOutportsPtr2)) return;
        }
        else if( dType == ssGetDataTypeId(S, "ptrtype3" ) )
        {
            if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, nOutportsPtr3)) return;
        }
        else if( dType == ssGetDataTypeId(S, "ptrtype4" ) ) 
        {
            if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, nOutportsPtr4)) return;
        }
        else
        {
            ssSetErrorStatus(S, "Input data type is not supported."); return;
        }


        if (!ssSetInputPortDataType(S, portIndex, dType)) return;
    }
} /* mdlSetInputPortDataType */
```

while in `mdlInitializeSizes` I set the inport's data type to be `DYNAMICALLY_TYPED`.

But Simulink keeps telling me I should set the inport data type in `mdlSetInputPortDataType` on a call to `ssSetNumOutputPorts`. I assume inside this function only the data type of inports may be changed.

Does anybody know of a solution to this problem? The only workaround I can think of is masking the S-Function and having the user to manually select the pointer type that he wishes to be processed. With data type propagation this seems messy and unnecessary though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set number of ports in mdlInitializeSizes. You cannot change that after that function. The only workaround is the one you mentioned.

Comment: You are right. After more digging this seems to be a limitation of Simulink. There is no way to get propagated data types of ports inside `mdlInitializeSizes`.

Comment: The doc at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/how-the-simulink-engine-interacts-with-c-s-functions.html has a "Model Initialization" diagram which shows which type of information is propagated at what point.